# Where can I file a bug for having a "primary" display checkbox in gnome-display-properties?

Tags: 11.04, multiple-monitors, display-manager

When working with two displays there is a question of which display is the "primary". In the case of Unity the primary display is the screen on which the launcher appears for instance. This property can be set using `xrandr`, but the gnome-display-properties utility does not give a GUI way to set this. This bug was also [raised upstream](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588041), and was apparently solved for Gnome 3.0. With the Gnome 3.0 vs Unity thing going on, I think that a bug like this should be addressed within Unity as well (and cannot be resolved upstream). I wanted to file such a bug in launchpad, but didn't know where to do this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add what kind of hardware you have?

Comment: Hardware: Laptop Dell XPS M1330 + 22" LCD Display by Chimei. I use my Chimei display as primary and the laptop screen as secondary. To get this result I use `xrandr --output HDMI1 --primary`. The main point of this question is how to request from the development team in Unity to add some sort of GUI option to the gnome-display-properties to that setting a screen to be primary is more intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to file this bug in launchpad is to type the following into a terminal session

> ubuntu-bug gnome-control-center

gnome-display-properties is part of the gnome-control-center package.  I usually prefix the headline "Natty" just to make sure its recognised by the Natty developers.

Comment: thanks fossfreedom. Did as you suggested, and files a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/763085) in launchpad again gnome-control-center for this issue

Answer (score 2):

fossfreedom's answer is correct. In addition to his instructions you can link the GNOME bug report to the Ubuntu bug report by following these instructions:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/Watches

This ensures that the 2 bugs are linked so that when someone needs to fix it they can find the corresponding bug report upstream.